# Is there an SE site appropriate for tech talk/questions? Specifically, current TV technology?

Tags: support

[Realizing my TV set is dead](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81011/how-to-open-a-32-philips-crt-tv-for-service), I now need to shop for a new one. I have not been in the market for years and years, so I'd like to catch up with the current TV tech trends. Is there a proper SE site for such questions?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [All Sites - Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) I can't seem to see any. There is the [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) beta site but "The operation of playing a movie whether it be digital or physical format" is listed as off-topic so it appears to be only concerned with the content of movies & TV. There have been a few related Area 51 proposals such as [Consumer Electronics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics) but they are now closed.

Answer (score 2):

This site isn't actually the right place for discussion about a topic, because it's oriented on specific questions with specific answers. However, if you get in the chat of a related site (this may work as well, SuperUser may be better), you can find people having a more informal discussion, and there you can ask for recommendations about whatever you like ;).